# Covert a list<string> into List<FieldUserValue>.Error "Property or indexer 'FieldUserValue.Email' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only"

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom, error, person-or-group

I have a `List<string>` which contain email addresses, and I want to create `List<FieldUserValue>` from it, I tried the following:

```
List<FieldUserValue> fuv = new List<FieldUserValue>();
List<string> usernameArray = userNames.Split(';').ToList();
foreach (var t in usernameArray)
fuv.Add( new FieldUserValue(){ Email = t});
```

But I got this error `Property or indexer 'FieldUserValue.Email' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only` on `Email = t`.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation ([FieldUserValue members](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/ee544881(v%3Doffice.15))) of the Microsoft, this error is valid because you cannot set `Email` property of `FieldUserValue` object as it is a read only property.

You can either set `LookupId` or `LookupValue` property.

Answer (score 0):

Hi SharePoint TestDev,

Email property only has getter. You cannot set it in the constructor. You can generate an instance of `List<FieldUserValue>` using below mehtod:

- [FieldUserValue.FromUser method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/ee537422(v=office.15))

Code:

```
List<string> Emaillist = usernames.Split(';').ToList();
List<FieldUserValue> fuv = Emaillist.ConvertAll<FieldUserValue>(x => FieldUserValue.FromUser(x));
```

BR